# Unregister format types

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to unregister some format types (core/code, core/strikethrough).

I tried the unregisterFormatType function. It doesn't work and console says the types don't exist.

```
Format core/code is not registered.
```

The line looks like this:

```
const {unregisterFormatType} = wp.richText;
unregisterFormatType("core/code");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to wait until the format is registered before you deregister it.

So something like this would work:

```
wp.domReady(function () {
  wp.richText.unregisterFormatType('core/code')
})
```